# Tableau Server Client - Embedded Dashboard Images Not Loading To Server

Tags: tableau-api

While using server.workbooks.publish() from the TableauServerClient in python, the images that I have embedded in a dashboard do not load into Tableau Server. These load fine when I manually load to Server from desktop. I've attempted using images saved from the Tableau default images location and from dropbox and from OneDrive with no success. Its obviously not a critical element of the dashboard but something that the client wants to see. Has anyone done this successfully?

Desktop:

[image]

Server:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issue, you must be loading a .twbx file for the images to be included. This was answered by a developer on github.

https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/issues/400